# How variable can change within extension of a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, extension-methods

I want a cell that has expandable and collapsable property. I want to implement the functionality in the extension. Can it be done this way.

```
protocol BaseCell:class{

    var isExpanded:Bool {get set}
}

extension BaseCell{

    var isExpanded: Bool{
        get{
            return isExpanded
        }
        set{
            self.isExpanded = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Hear is my expandable cell.

```
protocol ExpandableCell:class,BaseCell{

    func expand()
}
extension ExpandableCell{

    func expand() {
        isExpanded = true
        print(isExpanded)
    }
}
```

Hear is my collapsable cell.

```
protocol CollapsableCell:class,BaseCell{
    func collaps()
}
extension CollapsableCell{
    func collaps(){
        isExpanded = false
        print(isExpanded)
    }
}
```

Hear I declared my cell.

```
class Cell:ExpandableCell,CollapsableCell{
}
var cell : Cell = Cell()
cell.expand()
cell.collaps()
```

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what your question is, but extensions cannot add stored properties

Comment: What's the question?